# SSH RemoteForward fails with shared Control Socket

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding

My ~/.ssh/config contains:

```
ControlMaster auto
ControlPath ~/.ssh/socket-%r@%h:%p

Host hostname.example
    # TextMate rmate port
    RemoteForward :52698 localhost:52698
```

When I make an initial connection to the host, it successfully creates the master socket file at `~/.ssh-lachlanhunt@hostname.example:22`.

But when I open a new terminal and attempt to make a second connection, I get this error:

```
$ ssh hostname.example
mux_client_forward: forwarding request failed: remote port forwarding failed for listen port 52698
muxclient: master forward request failed
ControlSocket /Users/lachlanhunt/.ssh/socket-lachlanhunt@hostname.example:22 already exists, disabling multiplexing
Warning: remote port forwarding failed for listen port 52698
```

But if I comment out the `RemoteForward` line in the config, it's able to successfully reuse the connection, making it connect faster.  Is there any way I can configure ssh to support both multiplexed connections and enable the remote port forwarding, such that it only attempts to forward the port if it's the master connection?

My system:

- macOS Sierra 10.12.6
- OpenSSH_7.4p1, LibreSSL 2.5.0

Answer (score 5):

I figured out a solution.  I use the Match section with the `host` and negated `exec` keywords to test for the hostname and the existence of the control socket file. If the file doesn't exist, then this is the master connection, so setup the port forwarding. Otherwise, this is a slave connection and the forwarding is skipped.

```
ControlMaster auto
ControlPath ~/.ssh/socket-%r@%h:%p

Match host hostname1.example.com,hostname2.example.com !exec "[ -e ~/.ssh/socket-%r@%h:%p ]"
    # TextMate rmate port
    RemoteForward :52698 localhost:52698
```

Comment: Good stuff! For people looking to create a LocalForward or DynamicForward, change `!exec "[…]"`into `exec "[ ! -S ~/.ssh/socket-rmate ] && ln -sf ~/.ssh/socket-{%r@%h:%p,rmate}"` so if you're already connected to hostname1, you'll be safe connecting to hostname2 since it's checking a shared socket thanks to the symlink. This uses bash/zsh [Brace Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html) to more concisely create that link (ssh runs it in `$SHELL`). This must use `-S` rather than `-e` so it can operate on an existing-yet-broken symlink.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another solution that does not depend on `ControlMaster`:

```sh
Match host hostname1.example.com,hostname2.example.com !exec "nc -zw1 %h 52698"
    RemoteForward :52698 localhost:52698
```

This also works for local port forwarding and SOCKS proxying:

```sh
Match host hostname1.example.com,hostname2.example.com !exec "nc -zw1 localhost 52698"
    LocalForward 52698 remotehost:52698

Match host hostname3,hostname4 !exec "nc -zw1 localhost 1050"
    DynamicForward 1050

# Test for multiple ports
Match host hostname5 !exec "nc -zw1 localhost 52698 && nc -zw1 localhost 1050"
    LocalForward 52698 remotehost:52698
    DynamicForward 1050
```

These work by checking to see if the target port is opened. If not, it creates the desired port forwarding. [netcat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netcat) is a great tool for quick network tests and redirection. The `-z` option instructs netcat to just scan for whether a daemon is listening on the given port. `-w1` says you should wait at most one second in the event your packets are ignored e.g. due to a DROP firewall policy.